# Converting my google dashboard app from the UI service to the HTML service

Tags: google-apps-script

*I am a beginner to apps script so we're probably not off to a great start but here I go...*

I am in the process of creating a simple dashboard using cool (but recycled) code from the google team.

Whilst researching ways of improving the way the dashboard displays, I found out that the UI service is being deprecated (I first had to research what deprecated meant).

So now I realise I need to use the HTML service for my dashboard. The question is how do I convert the code below so it works on the HTML Service?

The code often refers to the variable 'app' which refers to the UI Service. I'm not sure if I just need to update that part or if I need to create a HTML file and start again. I hope someone can help me.

```
function doGet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EVpJrmuo7Er_a3Xsoy09VBBfQjEt5Ihdmm3JAWsPTIA');

  var data = ss.getDataRange();

  var ageFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(4).build();
  var transportFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();
  var statusFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(7).build();
  var monthFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).build();
  var nameFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build();


 // Create a table and pie chart

 var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,2,3,4]))
  .setDimensions(1000,500).build();

var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,4]))
  .build();

// Create a dashboard to bind the filters to the charts.
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
  .bind([ageFilter, transportFilter, statusFilter, monthFilter, nameFilter], [tableChart, pieChart])
  .build();

  // Create a UiApp to display the dashboard in.

 var app = UiApp.createApplication();


  var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
 .add(app.createLabel("Fix Tickets"))
  .add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
     .add(app.createVerticalPanel()
      .setSpacing(10)));

  var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
      filterPanel.add(ageFilter).add(transportFilter).add(statusFilter).add(monthFilter).add(nameFilter).setSpacing(10);

chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(pieChart).setSpacing(10);

  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);


  return app;
}
```

Comment: HTML file and start again, you'll use [google visualization api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) to create the charts and tables, and [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to serve the page. It's a lot more powerful than UiApp, obviously, you can use any Javascript chart/table, with HTML/CSS combination you'd like.

Comment: Thank you Kriggs. So will most of the code remain the same in the HTML file but I just need to change syntax slightly? The code was recycled from a Google youtube clip so I'm a bit lost as to how I convert it given it requires more than a copy, paste and a few minor tweaks.

Comment: Most of the code will change Because you will use a very different library and also very different framework (htmlService vs uiService). In htmlService make sure to use the iframe mode otherwise the visualization library wont work. Note that uiService is unlikely to go away even thou its deprecated. That said you do get a lot more funcionality if you go the html way.

Comment: Thanks Zig. I would like to go the html way but just don't know where to start as I am very much an amateur.

Comment: I hope I don't ask too much but is it possible to get some sample code? For example what would appear in the code.gs window and what would appear in the HTML file that would simply reference my google sheet and pass a table or pie chart to the webpage like the uiSservice was doing? Once I have sample code, I  find I can understand and tweak it but I am hopeless without some complete code to, as the rolling stones would put it, 'start me up'.

Comment: Maybe I do ask too much. Nobody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. Recently came across this. Maybe it will help.
[Converting UiApp to HTML](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/)